# E-R Model for quests composed by tasks

Tags: sql, database, entity-relationship

Let's say I got some quests that might be composed by 1,N tasks. All tasks can be completed gradually (i.e.: if the task is "Walk 5 miles" and the user walks 3 miles, I wanna save that data and display 3/5 miles walked). Users can have 0,N objectives and objectives can be assigned to multiple users.

If I design the model as follows ([ER MODEL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdClW.png)), where should I place the attribute to keep track of task progression?
Should I change the model? How?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand what you're saying is ... for the objective to be accomplished, the tasks have to be completed and the users are the ones working on the tasks.

If that's the case, consider assigning the user to the task rather than the objective.

So the task might be something like [taskID, description, quantity] ... [1, walk, 5].  User [userID, userName] ... [10, Sam].  And the relation between user and task could be [userID, taskID, quantity] [10, 1, 3].

That is, user Sam(10) working on task Walk(1) went 3 miles of 5.

Obviously a lot of details to fill in, but maybe that's a start.

Comment: What if I want the users to receive more complex and modular tasks, like "Walk 5 miles" and "Drive 10 miles", and receive rewards just after completing both tasks? That was the reason why I thought that objectives would be needed

Comment: What I would say is that those things could be accomplished in the approach outlined.  To address what you seem to be driving at would take a more complete understanding of the requirements.